# Serve Vue app from .NET 6 route in development mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, .net-core, single-page-application

I have a soliton with a .NET 6 web API project and a Vue project.
I need the web app and server to be behind our federated IDP while also the web app must **never** be served to an unauthenticated user; they must be redirected to the IDP before that happens.
The web server is already configured to function with the IDP redirections but what is causing headaches is the Vue side of the solution especially in development where the node server takes over serving the Vue app so the .NET server authentication hooks never happen.

What I think needs to happen is for the node development server to run inside the .NET project (probably the wwwroot), use a default route to serve the development version of the Vue app somehow and use the .NET server port to serve the Vue app.
But, from what I can tell there are no 'static files' to serve for a Vue app in development mode like there would be in production.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

I have looked at the new and old SPA templates provided by MS both of which don't seem to be appropriate out of the box for the mentioned requirements.
Also, attempted to manually wire up a fresh .NET and Vue project but with mixed results.

Comment: You can add middlewares to the devserver by setting the devServer.setupMiddlewares property in the webpack config (the devServer section of vue.config.js).   You should be able to add token validation and redirecting to either your backend or the IDP from there.